# How to fix "the name configurationmanager does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net, configuration-management

I already added the reference System.Configuration and still, I get recieving that error.
I am using VS2010. Here is the code

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MESConnection" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MES;Trusted_Connection=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies></compilation>
</system.web>
```

and the code behind:

```
private static string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MESConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have import System.Configuration reference ?

Comment: yes I added the reference and didnt even forget to add the using statement ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a using statement at the top of your cs code file:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Or fully qualify the reference:

```
private static string _connStr = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MESConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

**EDIT**

I see you haven't in fact referenced the correct assembly. You need to reference System.Configuration.dll *not* System.Configuration.Install.dll

Also the usual way to reference a .NET assembly in Visual Studio is to right-click on the References node in Solution Explorer and choose Add Reference...

[image]

Comment: I already added the using statement. And tried to add that line also. IT DOES NOT RESPOND

Comment: lol god forbid. I never shout on people, only on computers :) Thank you HollyStyles. It seems that I added the reference in the wrong place. those noobs...

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your solution explorer on the right-hand side
2. Right click on references
3. Select add.

Now you can add the configuration library and just access using its namespace